# User gets 500 error only on his profile none other

Tags: mysql, php, internet-explorer

I am running a site on php with a mysql backend. Things have been fine but suddenly one users account started getting a 500 error. Each user has their own profile so when they log into any box their internet explorer settings are the same no matter what box he logs on to. Does anyone know if this could be an internet explorer setting causing this? I have tried to debugging everything on the client side and no matter what I do he is getting rejected. He is getting into the config file (I am using a php framwork) which I can output some crap to thes screen but then it craps out. No other account is having this issue. I am not really an SA but the only thing I think it can be at this point is some setting within his profile which is causing this. This is also happening on firefox but instead of a 500 error I am getting a blank white screen. (I assume friendly error messages are turned on)

Comment: 500 means *internal* server error, i.e. web server. If no one else is experiencing the problem on the same URL, then I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Long shot, but check if this user has proxy settings  or some other Internet Explorer setting assigned by group policy that differs from other users. Ask your SA to run the *Group Policy Results Wizard* on this user and one other known good user, see if they differ in any relevant way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a few of these things:

1. Check that any string data in the current record doesn't contain any terminating characters such as apostrophes, commas, semi colons etc. that might not be getting cleaned before displaying. This could cause an error.
2. Can you create a new profile in this database for the customer? See if creating a new record/profile for the customer works.
3. If you want to try something, and you're running IE8 - try compatibility mode.

I can't really think of any other things to try - i don't know what you're using for a framework, or if the user has changed anything (or are able to) on their profile recently.